# Does every manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have a countable altas?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds

Definition 1

A surface of dimension k (or k-dimensional surface or k-dimensional manifold) in $\mathbb R^n$
is a subset $S\subset \mathbb R^n$
each point of which has
a neighborhood
in $S$ homeomorphic
to $\mathbb R^k$.

Definition 2

A set $A(S) := \{\phi : I_k
 \to U_i, i \in\mathbb N\} $of local charts of a
surface $S $ whose domains of action together cover the entire surface (that is,
$S = \bigcup U_i$), is called an atlas of the surface $ S$.

Since $A(S)$ is countable, but  I wanna know if every surface $S$ has an atlas? If not, could you give a counter example?

Comment: This is not a right definition of an atlas. What book are you reading?

Comment: Mathematical Analysis by Vladimir A.Zorich

Comment: What is $I_k$? What are the $U_i$? What definition of a surface do you have in mind? A 2-dimensional manifold admits an atlas by definition…

Comment: Then take another look at Zorich's definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second-countable and hence Lindelöf: any open cover has a countable subcover.  So, since your $S$ according to Definition 1 has an open cover by sets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$, there is a countable subcover which gives an atlas according to Definition 2.